# Which flag we need to set to ensure community version of EF Plus?

Tags: entity-framework-6, entity-framework-plus, entity-framework-extensions

With [recent changes](https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus/issues/510) in Entity Framework Plus, which is now depends on EF Extensions, how can we ensure that developers are using free community functionalities?

I have noticed there are two flags

```
        EntityFrameworkManager.IsEntityFrameworkPlus
        EntityFrameworkManager.IsCommunity
```

If we are using EF Plus Community version for EF 6 then which flag we need to set to ensure we are not accidently using Paid features?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To ensure you only use free features, you need this code:

```
EntityFrameworkManager.IsCommunity = true
```

This code is a little bit hidden at the bottom of the download page: https://entityframework-plus.net/download

**EDIT: Answer Comment**

> Silly question, but where does one place that setting?

Any place that's called only once. Here are some recommendations:

- Web App: Use Application_Start in global.asax
- WinForm App: Use the main thread method
- Win Service: Use the OnStart method

Comment: Silly question, but where does one place that setting?